# Error writing to file: Aspose.Pdf.Kit.dll. Verify that you have access to that directory

Tags: dll

I am trying to install AgilePoint on my server machine, but I am constantly running on this error:

```
Error writing to file: Aspose.Pdf.Kit.dll. Verify that you have access to that directory.
```

I am logged in a local administrator.
The vm machine is new and there has been no installation of Aspose at all.
I have searched in GAC and c:\ drive for Aspose.PDF.KIt.dll and I have not found a trace of it or Aspose for that matter.

Anyone knows what could be the problem?

Comment: Have you checked the installation log to see if by chance, the log, has the full path of the file its trying to access?

Comment: there are no logs created as installation stops and no log files are created. I checked the event viewer and that was not helpful at all. I get the same error as I have mentioned in my post above.